# regexp_replace replaces wrong part of the string

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, postgresql-9.2

When running:

```
select regexp_replace('( (test :Name (x) :Table (y) )','\s+\:Name \(.*?\)',' avner ');
```

I get:

```
"( (test avner "
```

But if I run:

```
select regexp_replace('( (test :Name (x) :Table (y) )','\:Name \(.*?\)',' avner ');
```

I get:

```
"( (test  avner  :Table (y) )"
```

Why is the `\s+` at the start cause matching till the end of the string?

Comment: I tested this in Regex101. The first regex with \s+ doesn't match to the end of the string. Have you set any flags?

Comment: The `\s` isn't matching till the end, the `.*?` is

Comment: @Wolph the "x" is enough for that and then we have the ")". Why should it match all the way? it's lazy...

Comment: What is your *desired* result?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter 
The desired result is replacing the spaces before name as well. Something like: "( (testavner :Table (y) )"

Comment: OK, the solution should be good. Just adapt spaces in the replacement, too. I guess you got that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is [(per documentation)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-MATCHING-RULES):

> A branch — that is, an RE that has no top-level | operator — has the
>   **same greediness as the first quantified atom in it that has a greediness attribute**.

Bold emphasis mine. Simplifying your question to:

```
SELECT substring('( (test :Name (x) :Table (y) )', '\s+\:Name \(.*?\)')
      ,substring('( (test :Name (x) :Table (y) )',    '\:Name \(.*?\)')
```

If you want the second quantifier to be non-greedy, change the first to non-greedy as well. Especially, since this doesn't change anything:

```
SELECT substring('( (test :Name (x) :Table (y) )', '\s+?:Name \(.*?\)')
```

And there is no need to escape the colon (`:`).

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3329)